# Javascript date function showing wrong date

Tags: javascript, date

The code below shows the day, month and year as:

```
6
3
116
```

Which is obviously wrong dates.

```
var date= new Date();
var day=date.getDay();
var month=date.getMonth();
var year=date.getYear();
    console.log( day );
    console.log( month );
    console.log( year );
    function next() {

    };
```

[Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/bpb5yo5g/).

Comment: PHP or javascript (title says PHP) ?

Comment: `Which is obviously wrong dates.` no, just read documentation what these method returns, it is day of week, month and number of years since 1900

Comment: Forget javascript Date. Use Moment.js: http://momentjs.com/

Answer (score 2):

`getDay()` returns the day of the week from 0-6 for Sun-Sat,

`getMonth()` returns the month from 0-11, so 3 means April,

`getYear()` has been deprecated and replaced with `getFullYear()` which should be used instead.

It just looks like all of these functions do something different than what you were expecting.

To get day of the month from 1-31: `getDate()`,

To get month like you were expecting, just add 1: `getMonth() + 1`

Comment: [*getYear*](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/6.0/index.html#sec-date.prototype.getyear) is not deprecated, though as you say *getFullYear* should be used instead.

Comment: @RobG Mozilla's reference lists it as deprecated. https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date/getYear

Comment: ECMA-262 is the normative reference, not MDN (which is a useful public wiki, but not a language authority). *getYear* and *getFullYear* have been in ECMA-262 since the [*very first edition* (pdf 325KB)](http://www.ecma-international.org/publications/files/ECMA-ST-ARCH/ECMA-262,%201st%20edition,%20June%201997.pdf) nearly 20 years ago, so not deprecated (though perhaps it should be). ;-)

Answer (score 1):

You're querying the wrong functions and misunderstanding the output.

`getDay()` returns the day of the week.

`getMonth()` returns the month, but January starts with 0.

`getYear()` returns the year minus 1900

You are probably looking for:

`getDate()`, `getMonth()+1`, `getFullYear()`

Answer (score 0):

Encoding in javascript for months from is 0-11 (not 1-12).

For year, you could use getFullYear() instead of getYear()

"Date.prototype.getFullYear()
Returns the year (4 digits for 4-digit years) of the specified date according to local time."

See: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date